# Windows UWP C#, images displaying incorrectly in stackpanel

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-10, uwp

So I have a function which downloads a list of ID of images, then I have a loop which adds a progressRing for every ID and set's the progress ring's name to the ID. I then have this function to replace the progress ring if it is finished downloading.

```
public async void getImagesLoop()
    {
        while (loop == true)
        {
            loop = false;
            foreach (UIElement child in stackpanel.Children)
            {
                if (child is ProgressRing)
                {
                    var ring = (ProgressRing)child;

                    if (await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.TryGetItemAsync("image_" + ring.Name + ".jpg") != null)
                    {
                       var tmp = new Image();
                        tmp.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 50);
                        tmp.Margin = new Thickness(0, 50, 0, 50);
                        tmp.Name = ring.Name;
                        tmp.DoubleTapped += Tmp_DoubleTapped;
                        tmp.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/image_" + ring.Name + ".jpg", UriKind.Absolute));

                        var location = stackpanel.Children.IndexOf(child);

                        Debug.WriteLine("Replacing " + location);

                        stackpanel.Children.RemoveAt(location);
                        stackpanel.Children.Insert(location, tmp);

                        Debug.WriteLine("Done replacing");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                       loop = true;
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It ends up skipping the first image though. (image_2.jpg, image_3.jpg) so image_1.jpg is missing.

Here is the debug as well:

```
Replacing 1
Done replacing
Done
Replacing 0
Done replacing
Done
Replacing 2
Done replacing
Done
```

I call the loop like this:

```
loop = true;
getImagesLoop();
```

Also, I don't think this is very optimized, so what would optimize it so there aren't memory leaks?

UPDATE 1:

So I ran it again and now the first and third image is there, just not the second image. Debug:

```
Replacing 0
Done replacing
Done
Replacing 1
Done replacing
Done
Replacing 2
Done replacing
Done
```

I'm going to guess it's an order thing, it seems the second one to get replaced ends up missing.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean when you say "it ends up skipping the first image" - doesn't `Replacing 0` mean that it did process the first image? You may need to clarify the link between your indices and your image file names.

Comment: @SimonMᶜKenzie I have 3 images (image_1.jpg, (image_2.jpg, image_3.jpg) On the application only image 2 and image 3 appear until I hit the refresh button which clears all the items in the stackpanel and starts the process over. I have a local cache and if it is found in the cache it uses that instead of downloading it, so there is something wrong with the code that makes it not display the first image for some reason.

Comment: As a basic rule you must not remove any in a list while you are processing a foreach. Because if an image takes more time to be loaded, you have an issue with the values.

Comment: It looks like you should create a control that wraps the functionality you want and use an ItemsControl to bind to a list instead of manipulating the StackPanel directly. Then each image/progress can have it's own state.

Comment: @Juan Pablo Garcia Coello So instead of using a for each, just use a loop that counts instead?

Comment: @WiredPrairie I'm not exactly what you mean by that. I'm assuming make a class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I took out the while loop and added changed it to this:

```
        foreach (UIElement child in stackpanel.Children)
        {
            if (child is ProgressRing)
            {
                var ring = (ProgressRing)child;

                if (await image_folder.TryGetItemAsync("image_" + ring.Name + ".jpg") != null)
                {
                   var tmp = new Image();
                    tmp.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 50);
                    tmp.Margin = new Thickness(0, 50, 0, 50);
                    tmp.Name = ring.Name;
                    tmp.DoubleTapped += Tmp_DoubleTapped;
                    tmp.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("ms-appdata:///local/images/image_" + ring.Name + ".jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
                    var location = stackpanel.Children.IndexOf(child);

                    if (location < 0)
                    {
                    return;
                    }

                    Debug.WriteLine("Replacing " + location);

                    stackpanel.Children.Remove(child);

                    stackpanel.Children.Insert(location, tmp);

                    Debug.WriteLine("Done replacing");
                }
            }
        }
```

and after each image was downloading, I just called the function.